# How do you call a widget update when the wifi status changes?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a wifi widget that toggles the wifi state. However, if the user changes the wifi state without using my widget, then my widget won't reflect that change. ex. wifi is on, user turns the wifi off through the setting, the widget will still show that the wifi is on because it hasn't updated.

How do I get the widget to update after the wifi status has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` to notify such changes

Register a receiver using

```
IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter();
mFilter .addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
registerReceiver(yourReceiver, mFilter );
```

and in the onReceive of `yourReceiver` class use

```
if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
//Do something
}
```

to update your widget

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE and android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED actions in your receiver.

Then in onReceive method, update the widget with the code below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class)));
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Regards,

Leonardo Oliveira